# Running a jit compiled tensorflow function inside a for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, montecarlo, mcmc

I am trying to use `@tf.function(jit_compile=True)` to run a markov chain monte carlo inside a for loop as per the [eight schools example](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Eight_Schools) using a different prior each time.
I am trying to run the following function from the example in a for loop:

```
# Improve performance by tracing the sampler using `tf.function`
# and compiling it using XLA.
@tf.function(autograph=False, jit_compile=True)
def do_sampling():
  return tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
      num_results=num_results,
      num_burnin_steps=num_burnin_steps,
      current_state=[
          tf.zeros([], name='init_avg_effect'),
          tf.zeros([], name='init_avg_stddev'),
          tf.ones([num_schools], name='init_school_effects_standard'),
      ],
      kernel=tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo(
          target_log_prob_fn=target_log_prob_fn,
          step_size=0.4,
          num_leapfrog_steps=3))
```

When I change the inputs and data set for the Monte Carlo I want to run I continue to get the same answer for my posterior, even when I am trying to run the Monte Carlo on completely different distributions and data.

I am guessing I need to somehow reload the function every time I call it? Or perhaps remake the function every time it passed through the loop? Here is an example in pseudocode (it's identical to the example in the link above, just in a loop):

```
for prior_estimate in prior_list:
     model = tfd.JointDistributionSequential(prior_estimate, ...)
     states, kernel_results = do_sampling()
     print(posterior_mean, posterior_std)
```

I tried removing the `@tf.function(jit_compile=True)` at the beginning of my function, which works,  but it is unpractically slow to test prior sensitivity. I also tried applying `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` at the end of each loop to try and see if that would clear the session but that does not clear the compiled function.